# Sending styled mail with PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail and I want it to be styled. As I know I can't use external file to do that. I'm using inline - style="" - styling. Eventhough I apply correctly it doesn't working. Mail is send but just as a plain text. Here's code that i use to send mail. By the way I'm using PHP-Mailer to send mail

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = $content;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; 
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "info@example.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";

$mail->SetFrom('info@example.com', 'Name');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress($person);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

**Edit(1) :** Mail Content

```
<div style='width: 250px; height: 250px; text-align:center; line-height: 250px>Example</div>
```

**Edit(2) :** I used table. Everything seems OK except styling.

Comment: Show us the HTML part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- mail content ? I edited question.

Comment: Do you check your mail with mail client (i.e Thunderbird, Outlook) or using WEB mail client?

Comment: @GRSEV With web mail client - gmail.com

Comment: Are you sure it's sending as plain text? That example HTML will appear as a plain "Example" word. You could make it more obvious that it's HTML by doing somehting like adding 'color:red;' to your styles. It would also help if you sent a valid HTML doc rather than just a fragment. You can tell for sure how it's sending by viewing the message source when you receive it - it should contain a single text/html MIME part, as you have not specified an `AltBody` nor called `msgHTML()`.

Comment: @Synchro I tried color:red but it didn't work either. I didn't get your last sentence. Should I use AltBody or msgHTML ?

Comment: No, you don't need to call them - you would use them if you want a dual-format plain-text and HTML. Anyway, the 'view source' thing is the important bit.

Comment: I'm sending `<td style="color: red"></td>` What I see on Gmail when I _inspect element_ is `<td></td>`. I can't use img either. I didn't tell bu I use AJAX. Does this matter? Edit: I tried sending `"Example"` and I got `\"Example\"`

Comment: In your example content you have not closed the quotes around your style attribute, and you should use double quotes rather than single. It always helps to start with vaguely valid HTML! Using a web inspector won't help, you need to view the source of the message using gmail's source viewer - see [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/can-i-view-the-html-source-of-an-email-sent-to-my-gmail-address).

Answer (score -1):

If you want support in all email clients (desktop and online) then you should avoid using div. Use tables instead. Also, font-family wont work, because you need to use !important if you want to change the font in gmail (online).

```
font-family: sans-serif !important;
```

Comment: That was just an example. I tried color:red or background-color: red to make it more certain. But they didn't work either. Edit: I used table. Everything seems OK except styling part.

Comment: try wrapping text into span elements. And apply style to those span  elements.

Comment: This is far too vague, and does not answer the question. Many email clients are much better than this - gmail is just the worst of them. Look at the [Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org) for details.

Comment: Why down vote? As you can see Zeki used div in his original code, I suggested him to use tables, which he did. One problem was solved, one remains. You know that gmail has 15% market share? Or should I say that is number one in online clients? So if Zeki has 1000 customers that are using gmail, he should do what exactly? Tell them to move to AOL? Or just ignore them without sending them an newsletter and loose profit because of "the worst client" ? If anything, your comment should be down voted, not my answer.

Comment: His question was about putting HTML content in email using PHPMailer. Your answer was about one specific rendering limitation of gmail. While it may be true, it is not an answer to the question asked.